# Creating string debug Vec for state machine

Tags: chisel

When designing a state machine in Verilog I will normally use `localparam` to define state names. Most simulators will be able to deduce this and during debugging you can view the state signal by name and not by a number. For simulators that don't figure this out automatically (Icarus), I will generally do something like the following:

```
`ifdef SIMULATION
reg [8*40:1] state_name;
always @(*) begin
  case(state)
    WAIT_SDS    : state_name = "WAIT_SDS";
    IDLE        : state_name = "IDLE";
    HEADER_DI   : state_name = "HEADER_DI";
    HEADER_WC0  : state_name = "HEADER_WC0";
    HEADER_WC1  : state_name = "HEADER_WC1";
    HEADER_ECC  : state_name = "HEADER_ECC";
    LONG_DATA   : state_name = "LONG_DATA";
    CRC0        : state_name = "CRC0";
    CRC1        : state_name = "CRC1";
    IDL_SYM_ST  : state_name = "IDL_SYM_ST";
  endcase
end
`endif
```

Allowing me to plot this signal in ASCII.

I have been trying to find a decent way to perform this in Chisel but I'm having no real luck. I currently use `ChiselEnum` and while I know there was a issue on the Github for trying to make it print a `localparam` it's not implemented yet. So I would like to add this to what Chisel generates.

Is there a way to achieve this, or something similar with current Chisel APIs?

One issue is I would need to create something and also put a `dontTouch` around it. If I can't wrap in `SYNTHESIS` ifdefs then it would likely create some logic I don't want.

Comment: This is for seeing the names in the VCD traces, right? Do you use gtkwave for viewing the VCD? I recently cobbled up a FIRRTL transform which generates gtwake filters (and savefile) for all `ChiselEnum`s defined in the design. It adds names (and optionally colors) to the displayed waveform. I can share it if it’s gonna be helpful.

Comment: @ɹɐʎɯɐʞ, yes. Although I use Xcelium for most of what I'm doing. But I wouldn't mind seeing a good FIRRTL transform if you have one you are willing to share. I've been meaning to try my hand at some FIRRTL transforms but haven't had the time to look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative method would be to automatically generate translation files for the waveform viewer.

Here's a FIRRTL transform targeting gtkwave. It creates translation filter files for all `ChiselEnums` definitions and a "gtkw" savefile populated with all ports and submodules.

https://gist.github.com/kammoh/b3c85db9f2646a664f8dc84825f1bd1d

You can use it with chiseltest (chisel-testers2) like this:

```scala
class MySpec extends FlatSpec with ChiselScalatestTester{

  val annos = Seq(
    WriteVcdAnnotation,
    GtkwaveColoredFiltersAnnotation,
  )

  test(new MyModule).withAnnotations(annos) { dut =>
    // test logic
  }
}
```

It's still a work in progress and if there's interest, I can suggest a PR for adding it to chiseltest.

Comment: This looks nice. I will check it out. Thank you